# How to consume wcf service using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, wcf

I have tried every tutorial and forums suggestions but it seems like it's not working on my scenario.

Currently, we have a WCF web service deployed from another server. The web service is inserting when invoked.

Tried to consume it by creating a simple html file but I'm receiving a bad request 400 but it is working when trying in SoapUi.

Here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="hit me" onclick="test()">
</body>

</html>


<script>
    var url = 'http://xx.x.xx.xx/KAViewWCFService/KAView.svc/'
    var Guid = "0F52118D-8704-E811-811A-FC15B428467C";
    var KnowledgeArticleID = "KA-01001";
    var StartDate = "2018-05-21T17:26:54";
    var EndDate = "2018-05-21T17:27:58";

    function test() {

        var response;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: url + 'UpdateKAViewDetails',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data:  JSON.stringify({
                guid: Guid,
                knowledgeArticleID: KnowledgeArticleID,
                startDate: StartDate,
                endDate: EndDate
            }),
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(msg) {
                alert(msg);
            },

            error: function(e) {
                alert("Error  : " + e.statusText);
            }
        }); 
    }
</script>
```

Note: When visting my url "http://xx.x.xx.xx/KAViewWCFService/KAView.svc/" it gives me 2 wsdl links. 1 is for svcutil and singleWsdl

Thank you,
rome

Comment: if your service request a xml, `JSON.stringify` won't help, you should create the xml inside the soap envelope. You can take the xml that is working with *SOAPUI* and reproduce in `javascript`

Comment: Thank you. I shifted from WCF to webapi.